# Deterministic one way communication complexity for message with arbitrary length

Tags: it.information-theory, communication-complexity, complexity

Let Alice have a binary string of length $n$ that it wants to send to Bob along a one-bit communication channel. However, Bob does not know the length of the message.

I have been looking into communication complexity material but everything that I found assumes that the receiver (i.e. Bob) knows the length of $n$ in advance.

I would really appreciate a pointer to martial that I should be looking into.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know if this algorithm is optimal (I looked at the references in the wiki page but no luck) or is there a lower bound result regarding this problem ?

Comment: What is a "one-bit communication channel"?

Comment: @usul Alice can send one bit at a time.

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for in more detail? We can do $2n$ by interleaving the message with "stop bits" that are 1 if the message continues or 0 if the message has ended. We can't do better than $n$. I think we can achieve $n + 2\log(n) = n(1+o(1))$ by first sending the length of message interleaved with stop bits, then sending the message itself.

Comment: Oh, you might also be interested in prefix codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code

Comment: @usul Thank you for the suggestions. To be more specific, I am looking for an optimal algorithm (in terms of number of bits sent) that can be used to send an arbitrary sized message from Alice to Bob along a one-bit communication channel. 
The algorithms that you suggested are asymptotically optimal, but I am looking for an algorithm that sends the exact number number of bits required (i.e. without dropping the coefficients).
Meaning, I know that $n$ is a lower bound. But is there a better lower bound than $n$. If so, is there an algorithm that has a matching upper bound ?